# structuremap inject a dictionary list of interfaces

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

Say I have a list of protocol handlers, and the client service knows which protocol to use based on an enum value, it would be nice to selected the protocol from the list of i/fs passed in.

How can I achieve this in StructureMap?:

```
   public EmailTransportService(interfaces...,
                               IDictionary<EmailAccountType, IEmailTransportHandler> transportHandlers)
```

At the moment, I'm using ObjectFactory with get named instance like so:

```
  _emailTransportHandlers = new Dictionary<EmailAccountType, string>
                                        {
                                            {EmailAccountType.Pop3, "Pop3Handler"},
                                            {EmailAccountType.IMAP, "IMapHandler"}
                                        };
```

then resolving like so:

```
 private IEmailTransportHandler GetTransportHandler(EmailAccountType accountType)
        {            
            return ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IEmailTransportHandler>(_emailTransportHandlers[accountType]);
        }
```

but I don't like this as its difficult within my unit tests to verify the calls to the handlers.

My service registry looks like so:

```
 public EmailTransportServiceRegistry()
 {
            Scan(x =>
                     {
                        ....                      
                     });

            For<IEmailTransportHandler>().Use<ActiveUpPop3Handler>().Named("Pop3Handler");
            For<IEmailTransportHandler>().Use<ActiveUpIMap4Handler>().Named("IMapHandler");
}
```

So basically I'm relying on named instances based on the dictionary list of protocol types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to have a static register method from the client service like so:

```
public static IDictionary<EmailAccountType, IEmailTransportHandler> RxHandlerRegistration()
        {
            return new Dictionary<EmailAccountType, IEmailTransportHandler>
                       {                                 
                           // following registrations use ActiveUp library for pop3/imap (http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/)
                           {EmailAccountType.Pop3, ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ActiveUpPop3Handler>()},
                           {EmailAccountType.IMAP, ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ActiveUpIMap4Handler>()}
                       };
        }
```

Then in the ServiceRegistry class:

```
 public class EmailTransportServiceRegistry : ServiceRegistry
    {
        public EmailTransportServiceRegistry()
        {    
            // other registries...    
            For<IDictionary<EmailAccountType, IEmailTransportHandler>>().Use(x => EmailTransportService.RxHandlerRegistration());
        }
    }
```